# Animating Text in Canvas - Android

Tags: android, animation, android-canvas, draw

Hi I have an app in android that draws texts on Canvas using canvas.drawText(). Now, I would like to animate the drawing of text such that it will be colored from left to right similar to a karaoke animation. Is this possible? Thanks.

Edit:

I am now able to do this using threads and redrawing the whole canvas everytime there's a new letter to be shaded or colored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using threads and redrawing the whole canvas everytime there's a new letter to be shaded or colored.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a main loop with [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame), handle time and each X sec modify something

For create the karaoke effect, i try to divide the sentance in 2 parts. One colored and the second in white.
Each X sec i move one letter to the other group.
Or with a layer half-transparent

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am doing this in Android so I don't think I can use the requestAnimationFrame you suggested.